# database:Could not connect to MySQLDatabase in joomla 1.5

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, lampp

I'm moving an old joomla site from a server to another, this site was not written by me. 
I had installed lamp on a new ubuntu server machine, I had deployed the entire application inside the htdocs of lampp root, and I had imported the database into the new mysql. I have created a user with the same credentials of hte user that I had found in the configuration.php file.
To be sure that the credentials working I had try to access to the mysql database with those and everything works fine. Under the host i had put 'localhost' because the db is on the same machine of the application, but i had tried to use the ip address of the server, opening the mysql port, and nothing... I still get the same error.
I had tried to find on stackoverflow and on the web too, but i always find that the problem is about the configuration, but i really look a lot at it and everything seems rigth to me.
What could it be? Is there any place where i can get more details about the error? A log file?(like incorrect login? or database not found?)
I would really like to solve this problem by my self, but i really don't know where to find more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, MySQL stores errors under /var/lib/mysql - you can check there.

Some questions:

- Is your configuration.php file using `mysql` or `mysqli`? Have you tried switching one to the other?
- What will happen if you create a simple PHP file (in your site's main directory) with a script that connects to the database?
- Are you sure that the user has write access to the `#__session` table?

Comment: I have found the error and it was in the $tmp and $log variables, i don't know why it mess the sql connection, but after i have edited those two variables everything works well.